# Prevent a new line before a theorem

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate, theorems

Is there any way not to start a new line for a theorem? For example, in the following example, I would like the word Theorem to be on the same line as the number 1.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{theorem}
            $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
        \end{theorem}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The code above produces the following:

[image: mwe]

Comment: Instead of `\newtheorem*` use `\newtheorem` to get the number. If you want the number first, then tweak the style. Using `enumerate` is not good. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: if you want the theorem numbers *before* "Theorem", use `\swapnumbers`.  see the documentation: `texdoc amsthm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could set up a theorem-like environment, called `shortthm` in the example below, that starts off with "**Theorem.**" and places its contents in emphasized (italic) mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\newenvironment{shortthm}{\textbf{Theorem.}\space\em}{\par}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item  \begin{shortthm} 
           Pythagoras showed that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
           \end{shortthm}
    \item  \begin{shortthm} 
           Euler showed that $e^{i\pi}-1=0$. 
           \end{shortthm}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there wasn't a number after "Theorem" in the question.  seems to me that `\swapnumbers` is what's really wanted, although the question really isn't clear.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Good catch! For unnumbered "short" theorem environments, the code becomes even simpler. Will post an update shortly.